# View logic with a block and conditional rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, logic

[image]I'd like some seasoned veteran advice on how I can find my answer. I know I have too much of the logic in my view, and I'm repeating myself but I'm still trying to "learn by doing" and this is about where I'm at to just get it working and I would learn how to refactor from there of course.

I want to iterate over a logistics created and if the logistics_title (passed through by a form of either "X", "Y", or "Z") matches "X" then display X in a div otherwise don't display anything.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
   <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
      <% if logistic.logistic_title = "Practice" %><br>
       <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
       <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
       <%= logistic.content %><br>
       <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
       <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
       <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
     <% else %>
      <%= puts "" %>  
     <% end %> 
   <% end %>
</div>
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
  <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
     <% if logistic.logistic_title = "Game" %><br>
      <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
      <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
      <%= logistic.content %><br>
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
      <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
    <% else %>
     <%= puts "" %>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
  <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
     <% if logistic.logistic_title = "Etc." %><br>
      <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
      <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
      <%= logistic.content %><br>
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
      <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
    <% else %>
     <%= puts "" %>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I know I'll need to write some helper stuff but a point in the right direction helps. 
Please be gentle, this is how I learn.

Thanks for taking a look and for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in that there's a lot of duplicated code and logic in your view. If I were going to do this myself, I'd probably change the controller so that your @logistics instance variable is split up into three instance variables, based on the title:

```
@practice = @game = @etc = []
@logistics.each do |logistic|
  if logistic.title == 'Practice'
    @practice << logistic
  elsif logistic.title == 'Game'
    @game << logistic
  elsif logistic.title == 'Etc.'
    @etc << logistic
  end
end
```

Regarding helpers, I think the link_to and logistic_edit_path helpers will generally be created for your helper if you're writing a standard Rails App and your Controller names matches the Model, so you shouldn't need to add those yourself.

Be careful not to use single equals (=) when you mean the equality operator. I think your code probably should look like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
   <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
      <% if logistic.logistic_title == "Practice" %>
       <br>
       <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
       <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
       <%= logistic.content %><br>
       <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
       <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
       <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
     <% else %>
      <%= puts "" %>  
     <% end %> 
   <% end %>
</div>
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
  <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
     <% if logistic.logistic_title == "Game" %><br>
      <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
      <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
      <%= logistic.content %><br>
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
      <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
    <% else %>
     <%= puts "" %>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="span4 hero-unit">
  <% @logistics.each do |logistic| %>
     <% if logistic.logistic_title == "Etc." %><br>
      <%= logistic.logistic_title %>
      <%= logistic.user.full_name %>
      <%= logistic.content %><br>
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(logistic.created_at) + " ago", logistic %> |
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_logistic_path(logistic) %> |
      <%= link_to "Remove", logistic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Remove? This action cannot be undone."} %> 
    <% else %>
     <%= puts "" %>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is the exact kind of answer I was looking for, it's people like you that have allowed me to stick with it for so long. The == is what got it working to the, I guess you could say v1, of what I wanted the application to do. And now from the 1st part of your answer I can research to get the code working into a "best practice version" Thanks again!